# How to write excel file with specific columns from a list in R

Tags: r, excel, list, xlsx

I have a list containing 150 different DF, formatted exactly like the sample table below:

```
   Date/Time       Depth       Pressure
   2022-01-09       65          70
   2022-08-09       65          NA
   2023-01-09       65          68
   2023-08-09       65          69
```

Each individual DF of the list is titled with the location from which the data was collected (i.e. Well A, Well B, etc . . .). I need to take each DF and make them into their own separate excel file, with their DF name used as the name of the excel file.

I loaded in my excel file to a list by using the following code

```
   sheet_names <- excel_sheets("./Data.xlsx") #gathering all sheet names
   
   list_all <- lapply(sheet_names, function(x) { #Read all sheets to list
   as.data.frame(read_xlsx("./Data.xlsx", sheet = x, range = "K2:M200")) } )

   names(list_all) <- sheet_names #Rename list elements
```

However, for the purposes of this task, I need to create excel files with a specific set of columns/column names. There are 30 columns, of which, I need to create a "DateTime" column which will have the Date/Time values, a "Depth" Colum for the Depth values, and a "Pressure" Column which will have the Pressure Values, the remainder will remain empty and are as such for correct upload to our database.

I have used in a very limited capacity openworkbook() and write.xlsx() but from my recollection, they were just copying the DF into an excel file and manually saving it.

I am having trouble finding examples or similar questions to solve this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am trying to create a script, that can take the single excel file, make it into a list of DF's, clean those DF's up, and then export them into individual excel files for uplaod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helpful?

```
#Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(fs)
library(lubridate)

#Create a place to stash your outputs
output_dir_path<-tempfile()
output_dir_path2<-tempfile()

#We named it above, but now we need to create it
dir_create(output_dir_path)
dir_create(output_dir_path2)

#Create an example dataframe
test_data<-tibble(
  date_time=seq(ymd_hms('2012-04-07 00:00:00'),ymd_hms('2013-03-22 00:00:00'), by = '1 week'),
  depth=rnorm(50),
  pressure=rnorm(50),
  random_col_to_ignore=1:50,
  site=rep(x = c("a","b","c","d","e"),10)|>sort()
)


#Edit it, break it up, and write them out
test_data|>
  #Make any edits you like before the "walk2()" function. 
  #In this case, I'm just removing a bogus column.
  #select(-random_col_to_ignore)|>
  #Nesting is much cleaner than lists, in my opinion. 
  #Much easier to work with:
  nest_by(site)%>% #Need magrittr pipe, which is fancier than base pipe, to pull next step off:
  #Then, walk through the data and write it out:
  {walk2(.x = .$site,
         .y = .$data,
         .f = function(site,data){
           
           write_xlsx(x = data,
                      path = str_c(output_dir_path,"/site_",site,".xlsx"))
           
         })}

#Open up the directory created by the script to view your output! 
#Helpful touch, I know :)
#file_show(output_dir_path)

#I wasn't clear on what you wanted, so if you want the other way around,
#let's just start with what we just output:
test_data_list<-dir_ls(output_dir_path)|>
  tibble(file_path = _)|>
  mutate(
    #Extract the site name out of the string:
    site = str_extract(string = file_path, pattern = "(?<=site_).*(?=.xlsx)"),
    #Read in the data useing the file path
    data = map2(.x = file_path,
                .y = site,
                .f = function(file_path, site){
                  readxl::read_xlsx(path = file_path)|>
                    #Add in the site col:
                    mutate(site = site)|>
                    #Remove nas from pressure:
                    tidyr::drop_na(pressure)%>%
                    #Change everything but date_time,depth,pressure to NA (also, if you put "" instead of NA, it will be a blank--whatever you want)
                    mutate(across(.cols = -c(date_time,depth,pressure,site),
                                  .fns = function(.x){
                                    NA
                                  }))
                })
  )%>%
  #Then, walk through the data and write it out:
  {walk2(.x = .$site,
         .y = .$data,
         .f = function(site,data){
           
           write_xlsx(x = data%>%select(-site),
                      path = str_c(output_dir_path2,"/site_",site,".xlsx"))
           
         })}


file_show(output_dir_path2)
```

Comment: So to clarify what I am looking for, I have an excel file with 100+ sheets in the format above. I was able to upload those sheets in a list of data-frames. I need to remove any row with a NA in the pressure column. I then need to export each DF from said list into an individual excel file. Each excel file need to be identical and have specific names for each column (as I said there are 30 specific column headers). The name of the DF will be input into the location code column, the date/time will be input into the date_time column.

Comment: And the depth and pressure columns will be put into the depth and pressure columns. The rest will remain blank but for accurate upload to our database they need these names.

Comment: I believe your answer was similar to the one above! Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Are you saying you only need the depth and pressure? Or all 30 cols, but they other 28 need to be blank? I updated the code to drop nas from pressure and select only depth and pressure, but you could use something like mutate(across()) to "blank out" everything but depth and pressure

Comment: I will add that anything you want to do to ALL dataframes can be done inside the map2 statement above in the code.

Comment: So, we need all 3 columns, but also additional columns that yes will be blank because that is how we upload our data to our databases. But thank you I will try out your edited code!

Comment: I edited my code. Now the workflow is like this: I create example spreadsheets to be edited, read them in, edit them, write them out

Comment: Do you want NAs or empty strings? I put a note in my code about that.

Comment: If the pressure column has an NA, it needs to removed regardless of data in the depth column.

Comment: Oh, I was talking about for the columns you want to "zero out". The code above should behave as you describe in your comment above.

Comment: Oh yes, either way it won't matter. The database reads NA and empty columns the same. But my previous remark stands. If pressure is NA then the row can be removed since its representing NA data.

Comment: Yep yep, the code above does that...see the `drop_na(` line

Comment: And how do I manually create the 'blank' columns?

Comment: Also I am unable to perform nest_by to the list.

Comment: Instead of a list, I would recommend you read in the files as a nested df as I have above. Nested dfs are much cleaner and easier to work with than lists. As for the blank column, see the block that starts with `mutate(across(.cols`

Comment: I have updated my original question to reflect how I uploaded the excel file as a list into r giving each DF of said list a name based on the excel sheet. In your code, your nest_by() the site, however I used the sheet names to identify the site and did not specify that in my code.

Comment: If you are really set on a list, deframe() is going to be your friend I think. You can apply it to my nested df above. As to the sheet name vs site -- that's an easy fix I'll leave to you! I was just trying to put together a general solution for ya...I'll have to leave this one here in terms of time. Sorry I couldn't be of more help! Don't feel obligated to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lapply()` or `purrr::map()` to iterate over a list. `purrr` has
variants of the `map()` command that are helpful here. `imap()` uses the
names of the list as a second argument. `iwalk()` is perfect here as it
silences the output of the function.

For the empty columns we can use `add_column()` to supply column names with empty character vectors `""`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Creating your data
df1 <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~"Date/Time",       ~Depth,       ~Pressure,
     "2022-01-09",       65,           70,
     "2022-08-09",       65,           NA,
     "2023-01-09",       65,           68,
     "2023-08-09",       65,           69)

# Creating dataframe with data for different well locations
all_wells <-
  list("Well A" = df1,
       "Well B" = df1,
       "Well C" = df1) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "location") |> 
  add_column(empty_col1 = "", 
             empty_col2 = "")

# split dataframe by location and write into separate excel files 
all_wells |> 
  split(all_wells$location) |>
  iwalk(\(x, i) writexl::write_xlsx(x, paste0("path/to/output/location/", i, ".xlsx")))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to automate the separation of the list into the DF? As I stated above, the list contains 150 DF and writing them out manually is tedious. Furthermore, I was able to create the dataframe, but the empty columns were not created. Furthermore, I need to be able to use the name of the DF (i.e. Well A) and put it into its own separate column.

Comment: If you already have a list of dataframes you only need the last line of code from my answer. The rest of the code is to replicate your data and for you to understand the conditions necessary for the last part to work.

Comment: Yes, but I never establish the location ID of the individual data frames. They were taken from the names of the sheets in the excel file. Thus, I get an error **Error in split.default(list_all, list_all$location) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0** when I try to input it.

Comment: My answer uses `split()` to split up the dataframe into a list of `data.frame`. Since you already have a list of data.frames you don't need that part. You only need the very last line with `iwalk()`.

Comment: That worked! One additional question, am I able to specify the output location?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to include a path for the output files.